# Submitting Spark jobs using python executable instead of spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

In a PySpark program, once the `pyspark` modules are added to the path, I can import `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession` and instantiate a `SparkSession`.

When is it possible to submit pyspark jobs using the `python3` executable (e.g. `python3 myApp.py`  instead of `spark-submit myApp.py`? I've tested this locally in client mode and it seems to work fine. What about `cluster` mode? What makes it necessary to use `spark-submit` in certain situations?

Using the `python3` executable to invoke the application makes it easier to debug the program using an IDE like PyCharm (to the extent I know).

Answer (score 0):

You need the following variabble in your code with the value depends on your python path and pyspark python path:

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark')
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']="/usr/bin/python3"
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON']="/usr/bin/python3"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = """
    --name job_name
    --master yarn
    --deploy-mode client / cluster 
    pyspark-shell"""
```

You can define other configuration as well.